# Why is it that sometimes using @name doesn't work?

Tags: support

There's a thread on BBC BASIC. One user posted an answer. I wanted to ask a question about this, and tried to use the @name tag to ping them.

Most of the time when I do this a little tag pops up with the user's name. This time that did not happen. When I posted it, it does not appear it parsed it at all.

I thought it might be because they posted the answer, but then noticed that it worked fine in other places when replying to the OP.

I've seen this before in other parts of the SE system, does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The little tag that pops up didn't pop up because it was unambiguous who you were directing your message at. The author of an answer is always pinged when a comment is posted on their answer.

You can also @ping editors, though their names don't show up due to an implementation detail. They still get pinged though.

Answer (score 1):

The author of an answer is never offered as popup. Only other who have written comments.

But as [wizzwizz4 mentioned](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/594/6659), he will be notified anyway.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. It was not clear what the "unambiguous" meant, which is why I would suggest it should be available anyway - what one person thinks is unambiguous is not what another user would.